# Create page from template save location

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitepages, template

On SharePoint Online we added a new content type to site pages that creates a new page from template.  This allows us to choose a template to create the new page.  We are using the following url in the content type /_layouts/15/CreatePageFromTemplate.aspx.

To use this, we navigate to the required folder and create the page from the New menu by selecting the content type. In the example below we navigating to meeting minutes.  The problem is when the page is saved it always saves to the root of site pages.  Is there a parameter or other method to have the new page save in the current folder?  thank-you

[image]